# Ignoring .svn directories with Wix Heat?

Tags: wix, heat

I'm using the Heat tool to generate Wix markup to include a large number of files and folders in my setup. This was working fine, but I just realized that since I added the source folder to my Subversion repository, Heat wants to include the .svn folders too.

Is there a way to tell Heat not to harvest files or folders that match a given criteria?

I am currently using Wix 3.5.

Comment: I only have 3.0 installed, so there might be a better way, but you could use `heat -t` and supply an XSL stylesheet to strip out anything under `.svn`.

Comment: Thanks Anton. I'd come across that option too so will have a look.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Unfortunately, today you'd have to use an XSL transform to filter out the "noise". This is a feature request for heat.

Comment: OK, thanks Rob. It would certainly be useful to be able to do this.

Comment: I read your answer and wondered how to apply the XSL on the WXS that Heat.exe generated. So in case someone is looking for it as well, all you need is to use Heat.exe -t flag. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8034798/wix-installer-using-xslt-with-heat-exe-to-update-attributes
http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/overview/heat.html

Answer (score 13):

Here is what works for me:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:wix="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">

    <!-- Copy all attributes and elements to the output. -->
    <xsl:template match="@*|*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*" />
            <xsl:apply-templates select="*" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />

    <!-- Create searches for the directories to remove. -->
    <xsl:key name="svn-search" match="wix:Directory[@Name = '.svn']" use="@Id" />
    <xsl:key name="tmp-search" match="wix:Directory[@Name = 'tmp']" use="@Id" />
    <xsl:key name="prop-base-search" match="wix:Directory[@Name = 'prop-base']" use="@Id" />
    <xsl:key name="text-base-search" match="wix:Directory[@Name = 'text-base']" use="@Id" />
    <xsl:key name="props-search" match="wix:Directory[@Name = 'props']" use="@Id" />

    <!-- Remove directories. -->
    <xsl:template match="wix:Directory[@Name='.svn']" />
    <xsl:template match="wix:Directory[@Name='props']" />
    <xsl:template match="wix:Directory[@Name='tmp']" />
    <xsl:template match="wix:Directory[@Name='prop-base']" />
    <xsl:template match="wix:Directory[@Name='text-base']" />

    <!-- Remove Components referencing those directories. -->
    <xsl:template match="wix:Component[key('svn-search', @Directory)]" />
    <xsl:template match="wix:Component[key('props-search', @Directory)]" />
    <xsl:template match="wix:Component[key('tmp-search', @Directory)]" />
    <xsl:template match="wix:Component[key('prop-base-search', @Directory)]" />
    <xsl:template match="wix:Component[key('text-base-search', @Directory)]" />

    <!-- Remove DirectoryRefs (and their parent Fragments) referencing those directories. -->
    <xsl:template match="wix:Fragment[wix:DirectoryRef[key('svn-search', @Id)]]" />
    <xsl:template match="wix:Fragment[wix:DirectoryRef[key('props-search', @Id)]]" />
    <xsl:template match="wix:Fragment[wix:DirectoryRef[key('tmp-search', @Id)]]" />
    <xsl:template match="wix:Fragment[wix:DirectoryRef[key('prop-base-search', @Id)]]" />
    <xsl:template match="wix:Fragment[wix:DirectoryRef[key('text-base-search', @Id)]]" />
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: +1 This is the same solution I use to filter out code contracts directories

Comment: If getting Unresolved reference to symbol errors, change `use="@Id"` to `use="descenddant::wix:Component/@Id"` as mentioned [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9163895)

Comment: I think a better solution to this problem is given here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9163895/3418322

Answer (score 1):

Subversion 1.7 has been released, and has [centralized the metadata storage](http://subversion.apache.org/docs/release-notes/1.7.html#single-db) as a single .svn folder per working copy. Therefore, I suspect your problem will go away if you simply upgrade your SVN client.