# How can I exclude SVN files from harvesting with heat (WiX)?

Tags: svn, xslt, wix, heat

I hate to practically duplicate existing questions, but the supplied answers haven't worked:

Here's what my .wxs looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">
<Fragment>
<DirectoryRef Id="SDKCONTENTDIR">
<Directory Id="dirE2EC21E8B765C611E918FB22F30721D1" Name=".svn" />
<Directory Id="dir7DC42F44E7FE9E20277B180A353D0263" Name="bin" />
</DirectoryRef>
</Fragment>
<Fragment>
<ComponentGroup Id="sdkContent">
<Component Id="cmp5E86312F0CA2C53B8173AECD6A428747" Directory="dirE2EC21E8B765C611E918FB22F30721D1" Guid="{E87F312D-9DA2-4A68-B6C5-BCE2FF90720C}">
<File Id="filB766A28A7577EB4311FD03CD707BC211" KeyPath="yes" Source="$(var.publishContentDir)\.svn\all-wcprops" />
</Component>
<Component Id="cmp6EF52B3E331F226299060D45F533DC07" Directory="dirE2EC21E8B765C611E918FB22F30721D1" Guid="{5EA6AB2D-20C3-4B07-8E0A-7C28135BE922}">
<File Id="fil83205196F05211A66F9D25A7A5496FBA" KeyPath="yes" Source="$(var.publishContentDir)\.svn\entries" />
</Component>
```

...

I'm using this .xsl code to exclude:

```
<xsl:key name="svn-search" match="wix:Component[ancestor::wix:Directory/@Name = '.svn']" use="@Id" />
<xsl:template match="wix:Directory[@Name='.svn']" />
<xsl:template match="wix:Component[key('svn-search', @Id)]" />
```

But I'm getting many "Error 48 Unresolved reference to symbol" errors as its not removing all child elements.

Ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is what I got working:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:wix="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">

    <!-- Copy all attributes and elements to the output. -->
    <xsl:template match="@*|*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*" />
            <xsl:apply-templates select="*" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />

    <!-- Create searches for the directories to remove. -->
    <xsl:key name="svn-search" match="wix:Directory[@Name = '.svn']" use="@Id" />
    <xsl:key name="tmp-search" match="wix:Directory[@Name = 'tmp']" use="@Id" />
    <xsl:key name="prop-base-search" match="wix:Directory[@Name = 'prop-base']" use="@Id" />
    <xsl:key name="text-base-search" match="wix:Directory[@Name = 'text-base']" use="@Id" />
    <xsl:key name="props-search" match="wix:Directory[@Name = 'props']" use="@Id" />

    <!-- Remove directories. -->
    <xsl:template match="wix:Directory[@Name='.svn']" />
    <xsl:template match="wix:Directory[@Name='props']" />
    <xsl:template match="wix:Directory[@Name='tmp']" />
    <xsl:template match="wix:Directory[@Name='prop-base']" />
    <xsl:template match="wix:Directory[@Name='text-base']" />

    <!-- Remove Components referencing those directories. -->
    <xsl:template match="wix:Component[key('svn-search', @Directory)]" />
    <xsl:template match="wix:Component[key('props-search', @Directory)]" />
    <xsl:template match="wix:Component[key('tmp-search', @Directory)]" />
    <xsl:template match="wix:Component[key('prop-base-search', @Directory)]" />
    <xsl:template match="wix:Component[key('text-base-search', @Directory)]" />

    <!-- Remove DirectoryRefs (and their parent Fragments) referencing those directories. -->
    <xsl:template match="wix:Fragment[wix:DirectoryRef[key('svn-search', @Id)]]" />
    <xsl:template match="wix:Fragment[wix:DirectoryRef[key('props-search', @Id)]]" />
    <xsl:template match="wix:Fragment[wix:DirectoryRef[key('tmp-search', @Id)]]" />
    <xsl:template match="wix:Fragment[wix:DirectoryRef[key('prop-base-search', @Id)]]" />
    <xsl:template match="wix:Fragment[wix:DirectoryRef[key('text-base-search', @Id)]]" />
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: I had problems with the solution when there are sub-directories underneath .svn. Also ComponentRefs are not removed.

Answer (score 23):

I had the same question, and found your answer.  However, I was unhappy with the need to specify the subdirectories of the .svn folder by name.  This can break if the .svn directory changes structure in the future, or if I had a directory named tmp on purpose...

When I ran your xsl against my xml, I additionally noticed that there were some directory fragments scattered around.  Being OCD and wanting to clean that up, I noticed that heat.exe has an option to "suppress fragments".  The actual effect was to make Directory tags actually nest under each other, which makes writing an xsl file much easier.

After deleting .svn directories from the nested tag structure, I still had a problem with ComponentRefs pointing to Component IDs that had been removed along with their containing directories.  Being an xsl noob myself, I had to do a little digging, but found that I could use "descendant::" in the use attribute of xsl:key.

In short, here is my solution.  Note, I have not actually yet tried to build the MSI with it just yet; that will come in a day or two.  But even if it isn't perfect, at least this might help someone else with the same problem...

Use: *heat.exe dir source -t excludesvn.xsl -sfrag -o files.wxs*

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:wix="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">
  <!-- Copy all attributes and elements to the output. -->
  <xsl:template match="@*|*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*" />
      <xsl:apply-templates select="*" />
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />

  <!-- Search directories for the components that will be removed. -->
  <xsl:key name="svn-search" match="wix:Directory[@Name = '.svn']" use="descendant::wix:Component/@Id" />

  <!-- Remove directories. -->
  <xsl:template match="wix:Directory[@Name='.svn']" />

  <!-- Remove componentsrefs referencing components in those directories. -->
  <xsl:template match="wix:ComponentRef[key('svn-search', @Id)]" />
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Wow, for a "noob" this is good, especially using the 'svn-search' key.  Bravo!  Oh, `<xsl:apply-templates select="@*|*"/>` is the same as your two explicit `apply-templates` lines.

Comment: For the `svn-search` key, you could also use `<xsl:key name="svn-search" match="wix:Directory[@Name='.svn']//wix:Component" use="@Id" />`. This XPath matches the wix:Component with a wix:Directory ancestor who has the name '.svn'. See [XPath Syntax](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256471(v=vs.85).aspx) for more information.

Comment: Excellent this helped me create a simple tranform to strip out symbol files from a directory harvest.

  <!-- Search for the components that will be removed. -->
  <xsl:key name="symbol-search" 
           match="wix:Component[contains(wix:File/@Source, '.pdb')]"
           use="@Id" />

  <!-- Remove all wix:Component elements that are a .pdb file -->
  <xsl:template match="wix:Component[contains(wix:File/@Source, '.pdb')]" />
  
  <!-- Remove componentsrefs for the removed components. -->
  <xsl:template match="wix:ComponentRef[key('symbol-search', @Id)]" />

Comment: I've spent hours looking, and this is the best solution to this issue I've come across by far. For anyone else who's using msbuild with the HeatDirectory task, note that adding SuppressFragments="true" is equivalent to the -sfrag argument.

Answer (score 0):

You get the "unresolved symbol" error because you filter out the Component elements, but leave the ComponentRef elements as is. Hence, those elements remain orphaned and reference missing Component elements. This gets caught by the WiX compiler.

As you probably guessed by now, filter out the corresponding ComponentRef elements as well. Hope this helps.

Comment: Yeah, there are orphaned elements, but the problem is that I can't work out a way to filter them out.  There are no ComponentRef elements in Heat's .wxs.  It is in fact the Component elements that are being orphaned since the top level .svn directory is being filtered out.  The svn-search doesn't seem to be working properly but I can't determine why.