# Wix Heat harvest: removing directories containing filtered components with transform

Tags: xslt, wix, heat

I have the following snippet of a .wxs(Ids ommitted) outputted from WiX harvest.

```
        <Directory Id="" Name="tr">
            <Component Id="" Guid="*">
                <File Id="" KeyPath="yes" Source="$(var.SourceDir)\tr\ZedGraph.resources.dll" />
            </Component>
        </Directory>
        <Directory Id="" Name="zh-cn">
            <Component Id="" Guid="*">
                <File Id="" KeyPath="yes" Source="$(var.SourceDir)\zh-cn\ZedGraph.resources.dll" />
            </Component>
        </Directory>
        <Directory Id="" Name="zh-tw">
            <Component Id="" Guid="*">
                <File Id="" KeyPath="yes" Source="$(var.SourceDir)\zh-tw\ZedGraph.resources.dll" />
            </Component>
        </Directory>
    </DirectoryRef>
```

And the following transform will remove the components but leaves the empty directory elements. How can I remove them as well? Given that I do not want to blanket remove all directory elements. Ideally, I would like to match them based on containing the component Id that is returned from the search.

```
<xsl:key name="zedResource-search" match="wix:Component[contains(wix:File/@Source, 'ZedGraph.resources.dll')]" use="@Id" />
<xsl:template match="wix:Component[key('zedResource-search', @Id)]" />
<xsl:template match="wix:ComponentRef[key('zedResource-search', @Id)]" />
```

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8737356/how-can-i-exclude-svn-files-from-harvesting-with-heat-wix) is similar, but uses the directory names which i would like to avoid adding a search for each of these because there are quite a few language variants.

Comment: Except for possible confusion to human readers, "empty" Directory objects don't do anything. (By empty, I mean they end up being the parent of 0 components, which goes well beyond the XML element structure.)

Comment: Thanks for the information. That confusion is what I hope to avoid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this is use a separate template to match the `Directory` element where all the child `Component` elements are in the key. You do this comparison with a `count`

```
 <xsl:template match="wix:Directory[count(wix:Component) 
                                     = count(wix:Component[key('zedResource-search', @Id)])]" />
```

Alternately, you can say you want to remove `Directory` which don't have a `Component` ref that are not in the key (so, a double negative)

```
<xsl:template match="wix:Directory[not(wix:Component[not(key('zedResource-search', @Id))])]" />
```

Comment: Both of those work and meet the criteria of not removing directories if other files are added to them. Thanks a lot this saved me a lot of time.