# Ignore a folder when harvesting a folder with heat

Tags: xslt, wix, heat, harvest

I am trying to run heat.exe to harvest a folder. The folder contains 3 sub folders, but I want to ignore one of them 'config'. I tried the following as said in this answer [How can I exclude SVN files from harvesting with heat (WiX)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8737356/how-can-i-exclude-svn-files-from-harvesting-with-heat-wix/9163895#9163895):

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
                xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi"
                xmlns:wi="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi"
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt"
                exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl wi">

    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

    
    <!-- default copy all -->
    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- Search directories for the components that will be removed. -->
    <xsl:key name="config-search" match="wi:Directory[@Name = 'config']" use="descendant::wi:Component/@Id" />
    <!-- Remove directories. -->
    <xsl:template match="wi:Directory[@Name='config']" />
    <!-- Remove componentsrefs referencing components in those directories. -->
    <xsl:template match="wi:ComponentRef[key('config-search', @Id)]" />
    
  <!-- Get the right sourceDir for the files -->
  <xsl:template match="wi:File/@Source">
    <xsl:attribute name="{name()}">
        <xsl:variable name="sourceDirStart" select="substring-before(., '\')"/>
        <xsl:variable name="sourceDirEnd" select="substring-after(., '\')" />
        <xsl:value-of select="concat($sourceDirStart, '\', $sourceDirEnd)" />
    </xsl:attribute>
  </xsl:template>  

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

But this doesn't work. Can someone point my mistake here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't say exactly what does not seem to work. This part (excluding an entire directory) works for me:

```
    <!-- Search directories for the components that will be removed. -->
    <xsl:key name="config-search" match="wi:Directory[@Name = 'config']" use="descendant::wi:Component/@Id" />
    <!-- Remove directories. -->
    <xsl:template match="wi:Directory[@Name='config']" />
    <!-- Remove componentsrefs referencing components in those directories. -->
    <xsl:template match="wi:ComponentRef[key('config-search', @Id)]" />
```

Perhaps you're referencing another `.xslt` file when invoking `heat.exe` by mistake?

I'm not sure what you wanted to achieve using the `<xsl:template match="wi:File/@Source">` part, but that does not appear to do anything here.  You may want to look at the `-var` command line option of Heat.

Also, you seem to have multiple references to `http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi` in your XSLT, I'm not sure that this is intentional.